# Matlab libsvm - how to find the w coefficients

Tags: matlab, svm, libsvm

How can find what the vector w is, i.e. the perpendicular to the separation plane?

Comment: and please give solution, how to find vector w in JAVA?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is how I did it [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28302-svm-demo/content/svm_demo/LinearClassifier.m). If I remember correctly, this is based on how the [dual form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine#Dual_form) of the SVM optimisation works out.

```
model = svmtrain(...);
w = (model.sv_coef' * full(model.SVs));
```

And the bias is (and I don't really remember why its negative):

```
bias = -model.rho;
```

Then to do the classification (for a linear SVM), for a N-by-M dataset 'features' with N instances and M features,

```
predictions = sign(features * w' + bias);
```

If the kernel is not linear, then this won't give you the right answer.

For more information see [How could I generate the primal variable w of linear SVM?](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/faq.html#f804) , from the manual of libsvm.

Comment: And how exactly do I use these to do manual classification? I am talking about the 2-classes case.

Comment: I've edited my question to explain, though there isn't really any point in doing it... it will return exactly the same result as `probs` in `[guess, acc, probs] = svmpredict(...);`.

Comment: Nope, it didn't really return the same result, it only returns -1s. I know it has no point, but I would like to make sure it is correct, and then I will simply use the weights in a separate application to 'manually' do classification without explicitly performing any SVM stuff. Thanks a lot, this is really a bottleneck in my project. Can you please double check this and see where the bug is?

Comment: it worked for me. Is your model trained properly? do `w` and `bias` look like sensible values before you do the classification with them? What options are you passing to `svmtrain`?

Comment: Here is what I do    model = svmtrain(yTrain, xTrain, '-b 1');
[predicted_label, accuracy, z] = svmpredict(yTest, xTest, model, '-b 1');w = (model.sv_coef' * full(model.SVs));bias = -model.rho;manPredictions = sign(xTest * w' - bias);  Thanks a lot for trying to help out Richard, I really appreciate it. P.S. Somebody please format the code.

Comment: Maybe I should compare with norm(w) to determine the sign(class)?

Comment: Ah, you are using an RBF kernel (to use linear, do '-t 0'). In order to compute the predictions, you need to put xTest through the kernel function. RBF kernel looks like K(a, b) = exp(-gamma*(a - b)^2). For each example, you compute K(a, b) with xTest(i, :) and each of the model.SVs, then you multiply this by the model.sv_coefs. The gamma value is a parameter - I think somewhere in model.Parameters. If you actually want to do this, for an RBF kernel, then I can give more details.

Comment: No, I simply want to use basic, linear kernel, which I thought was the default. So, to switch to this, I simply need to add the '-t 0' parameter?

Comment: yes. Then you should find that the code I gave produces the same result as the z result from svmpredict (unless '-b 1' changes this - if it seems wrong try '-b 0').

Comment: I do model = svmtrain(yTrain, xTrain, '-t 0');
[predicted_label, accuracy, z] = svmpredict(yTest, xTest, model, '-t 0'); it says Unknown option: -t

Comment: By the way, can you please also give me more details about how to use it with RBF also? Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Awesome, I actually got it to work for the linear kernel. And how would I do it with the RBF?

Comment: I'll need to take some time to look into the RBF kernel, I couldn't say how to find the prediction manually off the top of my head. I'm a bit busy but will try to get back to you in a few hours

Comment: phew, got it. It's a bit complicated! `arrayfun(@(i)a.svm.sv_coef' * exp(-a.svm.Parameters(4) .* sum((repmat(features(i, :), size(a.svm.SVs, 1), 1) - a.svm.SVs).^2, 2)) - a.svm.rho, 1:numel(labels))'` The idea is that we run the kernel function on each feature + support vector, then multiply by the SV coefficient, and finally add the bias. Parameters(4) is the gamma parameter.

Comment: and how to find vector w in JAVA?

Comment: Should the `'` after the `w` be removed? As `w` should be a column vector and the features are row vector. By the way, could you update your demo for MATLAB R2016a? Thank You.