# How to get weights for a LibSVM classifier in Java?

Tags: java, machine-learning, classification, weka, libsvm

I am using LibSVM in Java, as follows:

```
LibSVM classifier = new LibSVM();
classifier.setCost(C);
```

I am interested in getting the weights `w` and the parameter `b` from the classifier, so as to characterize the separating hyperplane in case of **linear kernel**:

```
w^T x + b = 0
```

I have seen [some other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10131385/matlab-libsvm-how-to-find-the-w-coefficients) that suggest how to do this in MATLAB or other languages. However, it is not clear to me how to do this in Java. If you go for the [documentation](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.stable/weka/classifiers/functions/LibSVM.html#getWeights()) you find the method `getWeights()` that, by reading the name, *should* return a list of weights. However, since:

- the return type is not the one that I was expecting (I would have expected something like `double[]` and not a single `String`)
- the Javadoc is not clear (quoting: "Gets the parameters C of class i to weight[i]*C, for C-SVC (default 1).")

it is not clear whether these are the weights `w` and `b` I am looking for.

I have seen [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/83140/libsvm-weights-of-support-vectors) another user having the same problem, but he did not find an answer to his question.

Thanks.

Comment: i am facing the same problem did you get an answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation you provided, it says the string returned by `getWeights()` is a string containing the weights (doubles separated by blanks).

So this should work:

```
String a = classifier.getWeights();
String[] weightsString = a.split(' ');
double[] weights = new double[a.length];
for(int i =0; i< a.length; i++)
    weights[i] = Double.valueOf(weightsString[i]);
```

Comment: Yes, but what about `b` in `w^tx + b`?